# ELF - Verifying executable memory regions

Tags: linux, memory, shared-libraries, elf

I'm learning about elf binaries. I want to manually verify that the code written in the program is in an executable region of memory (same for code for shared library that will be linked).

I have a simple program:

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

When I do:

```
readelf -a myprog
```

I get the following:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        08048154 000154 000013 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            08048168 000168 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE            08048188 000188 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        080481ac 0001ac 000020 04   A  5   0  4
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          080481cc 0001cc 000040 10   A  6   1  4
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0804820c 00020c 000045 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          08048252 000252 000008 02   A  5   0  2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         0804825c 00025c 000020 00   A  6   1  4
  [ 9] .rel.dyn          REL             0804827c 00027c 000008 08   A  5   0  4
  [10] .rel.plt          REL             08048284 000284 000010 08   A  5  12  4
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        08048294 000294 00002e 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        080482d0 0002d0 000030 04  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        08048300 000300 00016c 00  AX  0   0 16
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS        0804846c 00046c 00001a 00  AX  0   0  4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS        08048488 000488 000008 00   A  0   0  4
  [16] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        08048490 000490 000034 00   A  0   0  4
  [17] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        080484c4 0004c4 0000c4 00   A  0   0  4
  [18] .ctors            PROGBITS        08049f14 000f14 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [19] .dtors            PROGBITS        08049f1c 000f1c 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [20] .jcr              PROGBITS        08049f24 000f24 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         08049f28 000f28 0000c8 08  WA  6   0  4
  [22] .got              PROGBITS        08049ff0 000ff0 000004 04  WA  0   0  4
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS        08049ff4 000ff4 000014 04  WA  0   0  4
  [24] .data             PROGBITS        0804a008 001008 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [25] .bss              NOBITS          0804a010 001010 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [26] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 001010 00002a 01  MS  0   0  1
  [27] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00103a 0000fc 00      0   0  1
  [28] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0015e8 000400 10     29  45  4
  [29] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0019e8 0001ea 00      0   0  1
```

To check whether the code of the program is executable, I can see the `.text` section with the flags `AX`. Is the `X` here for making the code inside my `main()` function is executable ?

Which section will the shared library (e.g. glibc) be loaded into when the program is dynamically linked at run time ? I found explanation online which discussed use of GOT,PLT in context of dynamic linking. The only sections with the mark `X` are `init`, `plt` and `fini` (in addition to `text`). Are shared libraries linked into one of these sections to make sure their code is executable when program starts execution ?

(It would be great if some reference(s) could be pointed at when answering the above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the `X` here for making the code inside my `main()` function is executable ?

Correct. Although more than just your `main()` function is involved; there is some other code which is linked into your executable that is also contained in this section.

> Which section will the shared library (e.g. glibc) be loaded into when the program is dynamically linked at run time ?

None of them. The shared library is a separate ELF object, and has its own sections, some of which are executable; it is essentially loaded *alongside* your executable, not *into* it. That is, the resulting image in memory will contain both your executable's `.text` section and a number of other `.text` (and other types of) sections from all the shared libraries it has loaded.

For example, here is the content of `/proc/self/maps` from a running `/bin/cat` process on my Linux system. The format of this output is different from what `readelf` is showing you, but some similarities should become apparent:

```
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 08:00 32968                              /bin/cat
0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 08:00 32968                              /bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:00 32968                              /bin/cat
0242a000-0244b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fdf299a2000-7fdf29c6b000 r--p 00000000 08:00 949                        /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7fdf29c6b000-7fdf29e26000 r-xp 00000000 08:00 18508                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fdf29e26000-7fdf2a025000 ---p 001bb000 08:00 18508                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fdf2a025000-7fdf2a029000 r--p 001ba000 08:00 18508                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fdf2a029000-7fdf2a02b000 rw-p 001be000 08:00 18508                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fdf2a02b000-7fdf2a030000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fdf2a030000-7fdf2a053000 r-xp 00000000 08:00 18255                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fdf2a246000-7fdf2a249000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fdf2a250000-7fdf2a252000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fdf2a252000-7fdf2a253000 r--p 00022000 08:00 18255                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fdf2a253000-7fdf2a254000 rw-p 00023000 08:00 18255                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fdf2a254000-7fdf2a255000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffd516aa000-7ffd516cb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd517f9000-7ffd517fb000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd517fb000-7ffd517fd000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

In particular, you can see three sections were loaded from `/bin/cat` at the top: the first one is executable (`r-xp`), the second one is read-only (`r--p`), and the third is read-write (`rw-p`). Additionally, there are a number of executable and non-executable segments mapped from `libc-2.19.so` below that, as well as from `ld-2.19.so` (the dynamic linker).

(There are also some somewhat mysterious segments appearing in this dump, including `[vdso]` and `[vsyscall]`. These are mapped into the process by the kernel, and are difficult to explain; I won't get into them here.)